# SAS PHREG test for trend?

Tags: sas, trend, hazard

I am running a PHREG model with mortality as the outcome and quartiles of protein X as my predictor (where quartile 1= ref). I was able to get the HR for quartile 2, 3, and 4, and their respective p-values- which are not significant (0.8, 0.4, 0.2) and now wondering if there is a way to test for a trend in the HRs?? Any suggestions/tips for the analysis would be appreciated!

Comment: HRs have an assumption of constant. Quartiles usuually refer to the 25% of population left here, but I suspect you're using it here relative to your variable. Can you explain in some more detail what you're looking for here? Is it a trend of HR across different levels of your variable?

Comment: FYI - this question belongs on CrossValidated, not StackOverflow.

Comment: I am not a statistician but code for them. I believe you'd just want to run the quartile as a continuous variable to do the test for trend - in other words, remove the CLASS statement in the PHREG.